# How can I retrieve 3rd & 4th Parameter of MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP' Open method?

Tags: com, vbscript, httprequest

I am using the following code:

```
 Set objXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
 objXMLHTTP.Open "POST", URL + "/" + Method, false,UID,PASSWORD
 objXMLHTTP.Send ' Not sending custom parameters
 WScript.Sleep 500
 Loop
 MsgBox objXMLHTTP.responseTEXT
```

Is there a way to retrieve the UID and PASSWORD sent inside the URL (I have got the code for the web service)?

PS: The information I seek is not in the HttpRequest.Current.Request.Headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK you need to set the header `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` for a POST request, so try changing your code to this:

```
Set objXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
objXMLHTTP.Open "POST", URL + "/" + Method, False, UID, PASSWORD
objXMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
objXMLHTTP.Send
```